# subclass of a serializable class needs to be serializable?

Tags: java, servlets

If I have 3 classes say A and It Implements java.io.Serializable . And I have B ,which is subclass of A. If I want to serialize B , B also implements java.io.Serializable. If not Why HttpServlet implements java.io.Serializable as GenericServlet already implements it. Please clarify me .

Thanks in Advance
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, not necessary.

Note that `Serializable` is just a marker interface. So, by explicitly implementing it, you're basically saying (**marking**) that you are aware of the Serializable restrictions/contract and designed accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, it doesn't need to implement java.io.Serializable. Maybe it's simply being done for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other folks, it does not have any technical implications (`HttpServlet` implementing `java.io.Serializable`). Its more from the clarity point of view which allows a developer to quickly view if this class is serializable or not. Its there all around JDK. Checkout the `java.lang.Number` and its subclasses.

Its similar to best practices of importing packages wherein we should avoid wildcards (java.io.*). Technically, there is nothing wrong is using wildcard (unless there are conflicting classnames) but importing classes with fully qualified classnames is cleaner,